# Is it possible to lock cells in a shared excel per user using a macro?

Tags: excel, macros

I'm working on an Excel sheet that is to be shared and opened on SharePoint (not in-browser editing). I understand there is a feature in Excel to lock a range of cells to only be editable by specified domain users.

My question is: would it be possible to automate this locking mechanism in a macro so that if an empty cell is edited by a user then they get ownership (so it is locked for everyone except them) and if they clear the cell then it becomes unlocked for everyone else?

Comment: You can use a macro to create User editable ranges, however the difficulty comes when trying to add the permission to those User editable ranges, take a look at this http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Excel/AddEditRange.htm

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this isn't an answer per se, but it is a starting point I hope. This works by creating a User editable range, and assign the current user permission to edit this cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim userName As String, ws As Worksheet, ual As UserAccessList, aer As AllowEditRange, usr As UserAccess, thisCell As String, rngName As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Unprotect
    thisCell = Target.Address
    rngName = Replace(thisCell, "$", "")
    userName = Application.userName
    userName = Replace(userName, " ", ".")
    userName = userName & "@gmail.com"
On Error GoTo Handler
    Set aer = ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add(rngName, Range(thisCell), "pass1")
    Set usr = aer.Users.Add(userName, True)
    ws.Protect
    Exit Sub
Handler:
    MsgBox "Some error somewhere"
    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges(rngName).Delete
End Sub
```

I can only get this working using our network email addresses (which I have changed for the purpose of this example). And it is only tested on one user, no idea how it will work if the same file is edited by anyone else.

Big problem I can foresee though is for the user protected ranges to work, the sheet has to be locked, but if its locked you won't be able to edit other cells, unless you unlock all the cells, in which case user protected cells are obsolete.